# Error when subscribing to time observable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a clock on my app that uses an `observable` to update every second:

clock.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';

@Injectable()
export class ClockService {

  mydate: Date;

  constructor() {}

  getClock(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      setInterval(()=>{
        this.mydate = new Date();
        observer.next(this.mydate);

      }, 1000);
    });
  }

}
```

header.component:

```
...
private mydate: Date;

...
constructor(private clockService: ClockService, private alertService: AlertsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mydate = this.clockService.getClock().subscribe(res => this.mydate = res);;
  }
```

I'm getting an error:
`error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'Subscription'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mydate = this.clockService.getClock().subscribe(res => this.mydate = res);;
  }
```

This is wrong. You're binding `subscription` to `Date`, as the error says.
Change to this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clockService.getClock().subscribe(res => this.mydate = res);;
  }
```